# “What are” or “What is” in a quiz?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, questions

I want to ask a typical quiz question for children.

- *In a park, there are 10 bird boxes attached to several trees.*

The answer in this particular case is plural: bird boxes.

Which question is correct?

- A: *What is hanging in the trees?*
- B: *What are hanging in the trees?*

B sounds all wrong to me, though more grammatically correct, but then, I’m not a native speaker.

B also gives some of the answer away.

More importantly, I wonder if B would be confusing for kids as it is unusual to hear it that way?

The one UK native speaking editor I asked recommended ‘are’, but I’m not convinced?

Thoughts?

Comment: Is giving some of the answer away really an issue for a children's quiz?

Comment: @KillingTime No, giving away some of the answer is not an issue, you’re right. It’s more that I think it will be confusing and ‘sound wrong’ for kids. Just added that in.

Comment: Is this a question about a picture showing trees with bird boxes in them? Otherwise, it seems oddly phrased.

Comment: @KateBunting it is not a picture. There are real trees and real bird boxes. So alternative would be? Something like: What can you see hanging in the trees?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: The only alternative a logician would accept here is  C: What is or are hanging in the trees? But that's excessively clunky. 'What can you see hanging in the trees?' is a paraphrase that gets round the problem. But note that '[Some] bird boxes' are not incorrect answers to all these variants.

Comment: The problem with "What can you see ..." in a quiz is that if the answer is truthful, it must also be correct.

Comment: What things are hanging from the trees?

Comment: What **is** in garden there? Answer: Squirrels. This is not a grammar question at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to Huddleston, default value of "what" is singular (Huddleston,The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, Chapter 5, 18.3, d) Interrogatives).

When asking a question, you're coming from a position of ignorance, so how would you know if it's singular or plural?

Comment: The question is a quiz for children where the question asker _knows the answer_.

Comment: You're confusing author and voice. You could say the quiz, not the writer, is asking the question.

Comment: The question is a quiz for children who won't know the CGEL pronouncement on the default value of 'what', and 'what is ...' will throw some of the kids, who will not feel happy with the felicitousness of the answer '[There are] 3 boxes.'  Pragmatics demands a rephrasing.

Comment: I have the impression Konni is writing a textbook, so it might be tricky, but this IS a learning opportunity! Pragmatics demands teaching the kids "what is..." "there are..."! Potatoe Potahto.

Comment: 'In a park, there are 10 bird boxes attached to several trees.
The answer in this particular case is plural: bird boxes. ... Which question is correct?

A: "What is hanging in the trees?"

B: "What are hanging in the trees?" ' indicates a target age-group who will not understand illogical pragmatic overrides where 'A' and "10 boxes" are permitted to co-exist; pragmatics demands flexible, sometimes conflicting, treatments in different registers.

Answer (score -1):

Bear in mind that the antecedent/referent of the interrogative pronoun "what" is xenophoric – it is unknown to the listener/reader. The **default** is the singular antecedent/referent.

1. Compare: Q:"What **is** making that noise?" A: "The triplets; they **are** fighting."

**NB** here, "what" turns out to be plural and human. "What" – rather than “who” - is also correct because the referent/antecedent of **what** is unknown.

In practice, unlike 1. above, you know the answer and you know it is plural – there is also the clue that whatever the answer is, it is in several trees:

> A: What is hanging in the trees?

This would be the standard question, and I would expect the answer to be one item or one type of item: "A birdbox/Birdboxes."

> B: What **are** hanging in the trees?

This is said where the speaker knows the answer is plural.

I would expect the answer to be either (i) several similar items - "birdboxes", or (ii) various items: "Some birdboxes, some decorations, and some balls of fat."

When you use this question as a teaching aid, if you use "is", then you are being neutral: you give no clue as to the number or type of items. If you use "are" you are implying more than one item or types of item.

**Conclusion:** There is no real answer to this.

Comment: If this question belongs on ELU, the question the kids are asked needs rephrasing.